# iOS: Button to access next Tableview cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a main view controller which is a tableview, after selecting a cell from the table view, another view is displayed. How can I create buttons to access and display the next and previous cell's view? I have the toolbar and buttons set, I just need help with the code to access and push the next view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the data for the `tableView` (presumably an array containing info for the cells) to your `detailViewController`, then you can navigate through the items that way.

When you select a row, send the `indexPath.row` to the `detailViewController` as a property, e.g. `int selectedRow`. Then wire up two buttons, one that decrements this parameter and another that increments it.

Comment: I'm not using a detailViewController.

Comment: @Nadeem When you write "another view is displayed", I am calling this `detailViewController` and assuming it is presented modally. If so, then you can do what I propose.

Answer (score 1):

You are just looking at basic `NavigationController` and `TableViewcontroller` properties. If you want to navigate between two views then you need a Navigation Controller, and for choosing cells you need to work with the tableView.

You just need to go to the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of your table view controller, and after selecting a row, you need to push your view controller to your next view `[self.navigationController pushViewController: nextController animated:YES];`. This will take control to your nextView, and you will have a back button which will bring you back to the previous view.

If you want to pass data between the views, you will need to

1. Set them as properties and reference the classes to access them.
2. Use `NSUserDefaults`.