# iOS: How to change a label with a next and a back button (DetailView)

Tags: ios, uibutton, tableview, master-detail

I've got a Master-Detail Application and in my DetailView I have got a "back" and "next" button.
How the buttons should work:
If I click on the back/next button, the label (which comes from a TableView with SearchBar from the MasterView) should change to the previous/next entry of the TableView.
My problem is that I don't know how I can do that.
I searched in this forum and found this topic [iOS: Button to access next Tableview cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779546/ios-button-to-access-next-tableview-cell), but I don't understand it (I am new in developing for iOS).
Can you help me please?

EDIT:
It is an iPhone App, with Storyboard and segue from MasterView to DetailView.
And it is a dynamic TableView.

Comment: Dynamic or static `UITableView`?

Comment: There are different ways master/detail can be related and the answer will be slightly different for each.  Is this an iPad split view (with or without a storyboard), or a segue from master to detail, or a detail created from a xib file when a cell is tapped?

Comment: The TableView got one dynamic prototypecell

Comment: @Phillip Mills: Oh sorry, I forgot to wrote that it is an iPhone app with Storyboard and with a segue from master to detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic process is to make the class that can provide the data be a delegate of the one that needs it.

- Create a new protocol.
- Make the master controller implement the protocol.
- Give the detail controller a property that refers to an object of
  that protocol.
- In `prepareForSeque:`, set the detail's delegate to the master
  controller.
- When the buttons are tapped, call your delegate for new data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain it more precisely from point 3? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: When you specify a type, you can declare that if conforms to a protocol by using syntax like `@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyProtocol> dataDelegate;`.  In this case, you want a delegate property in the detail controller that points to the master controller.

Comment: I created a protocol (DPApp.h `@protocol DPApp <NSObject>`). And then I implement it to the MasterViewController.m `#import DPApp.h`. Also I created now the property in the DetailView.h `@property (nonatomic, strong) id<DPApp> dataDelegate;` after `#import DPApp.h`. But now I don't understand point 4 & 5. Can you explain it please? Thank you :)

Comment: Did you read about `prepareForSegue:`?  When the segue starts, that method is called if you've defined it on the view controller that's the initiator of the segue.  The segue object passed into the method has a reference to the destination controller.  You can cast it as a detail controller and set its `dataDelegate` to `self`.  Then, on your button taps, you simply call something like `myLabel.text = [dataDelegate back];` or `myLabel.text = [dataDelegate next];`...depending on how you've defined the protocol method(s).

Comment: My prepareForSegue is looking like this [link](http://i.imgur.com/KVMZR.png). My problem is that I don't know how to realize the things you say. I don't have any protocol methods because I don't know what methods I need. Can you give me an example with my app? My DetailView [link](http://i.imgur.com/XHmUP.png)